# Отключить пустые value

Tags: javascript

У меня в шаблоне фильтра упорно не хочет работать условие с $device_type Причем если я вывожу echo "$device_type" Я вижу что значение меняется и на пк и на моб, то есть переменная не пустая. Но в самом условии типа if($device_type == 'desktop') не работает и выходит ошибка Uncaught ReferenceError: $device_type is not defined Прописывал и это $device_type = cmsRequest::getDeviceType(); не помогает. Может что посоветуете?

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
    if($device_type != 'desktop'){//не показываем на пк
    $(function(){       
        $("#p30_filter227 option[value='']").remove();  //улица
        $("#p32_filter227 option[value='']").remove();//номер дома
        $("#p34_filter227 option[value='']").remove();//ориентир
        $("#p37_filter227 option[value='']").remove();//санузел
        $("#p38_filter227 option[value='']").remove();//техника 
    });
    };
    if($device_type == 'desktop'){//показываем на пк
    $(function(){       
         $("#p30_filter227 option[value='']").remove(); //улица
    });
    };
```

addBottom(ob_get_clean()); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Советую: Вы не объявляете переменную `$device_type`, a значение ей присваиваете после того, как выполняется приведенный код.

```
$(function(){       
  if($device_type != 'desktop'){//не показываем на пк
    $("#p30_filter227 option[value='']").remove();  //улица
    $("#p32_filter227 option[value='']").remove();//номер дома
    $("#p34_filter227 option[value='']").remove();//ориентир
    $("#p37_filter227 option[value='']").remove();//санузел
    $("#p38_filter227 option[value='']").remove();//техника 
  } else {//показываем на пк
     $("#p30_filter227 option[value='']").remove(); //улица
  }
});
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, переменная объявлена, данные в ней есть. Очень странная ошибка. Uncaught ReferenceError: $device_type is not defined
    <anonymous>
    jQuery 2
        e
        t
Может  jQuery не подключен, как проверить можно?

Comment: @KoRn "переменная объявлена" - где?

Comment: Чуть выше на этой же странице  $device_type = cmsRequest::getDeviceType();

Comment: @KoRn Вы сейчас что, говорите о переменной в php коде?

Answer (score 0):

В общем писал не правильно, вот решение.

```
<?php if($device_type != 'desktop') { //не десктопы ?>
        <?php ob_start(); ?>
            <script>
                $(function(){       
                    $("#p30_filter231 option[value='']").remove();  //улица
                    $("#p32_filter231 option[value='']").remove();//номер дома
                    $("#p34_filter231 option[value='']").remove();//ориентир
                    $("#p37_filter231 option[value='']").remove();//санузел
                    $("#p38_filter231 option[value='']").remove();//техника 
                });
            </script>
        <?php $this->addBottom(ob_get_clean()); ?>
<?php } ?>
```